# NPM not working on Virtualbox shared folder under Ubuntu on a Windows 10 host

Tags: node.js, npm, vagrant, virtualbox, npm-install

I'm trying to set-up a development environment on a Virtualbox machine using Vagrant. I'm using Windows 10 as a host machine, and ubuntu/bionic64 as a guest machine.

My `package.json` file is located under a shared directory between the host machine and the guest machine. However whenever I run `npm install --no-bin-links` I do get the following error:

```
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! syscall open
npm ERR! path /home/vagrant/www/wp-content/plugins/my-plugin/node_modules/array-initial/node_modules/is-number/package.json.1640612897
npm ERR! errno -2
npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/home/vagrant/www/wp-content/plugins/my-plugin/node_modules/array-initial/node_modules/is-number
/package.json.1640612897'
npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/vagrant/.npm/_logs/2021-01-19T05_31_47_272Z-debug.log
```

Inside the guest machine, if I copy the `package.json` and `package-lock.json` into another directory that is not shared, and then run `npm install` everything works perfectly.

```sh
mkdir /tmp/test/
cp package.json package-lock.json /tmp/test/
cd /tmp/test/ && npm install 
# NPM Packages are installed successfully!
```

I think this error is specific to Windows, as I've been a user of Ubuntu for years, and never had a similar issue. I only started using Windows a week ago.

The strange thing is, I also have another development environment on the same machine, and NPM works just fine, without any issues on shared folders!

I used the `--no-bin-links`, so I don't think the issue has anything to do with the symbolic links.

Looking into the `strace` output, I can't see when this file `node_modules/array-initial/node_modules/is-number /package.json.1640612897` was created.

[NPM log](https://gist.github.com/kerkouch/9fcfd3ee6bd6e54c06a8cdcc3360d07f)

[Strace log](https://gist.github.com/kerkouch/a3262a0956e0f012a9c0597041013d60)

Comment: I have the same problem with Ubuntu 22 host, Ubuntu 18 guest.

Comment: @daw the issue is caused by symbolic links. You can copy packages.json and packages-lock.json to a temporary directory inside the host and then run the build from there.

Comment: yeah it works in normal guest dirs but the reason for running the build in a shared dir was to use tools that were incompatible with the host on shared data... but no luck

Answer (score 0):

You need to enable symbolic links:

```
VBoxManage setextradata YOUR_VM_NAME VBoxInternal2/SharedFoldersEnableSymlinksCreate/YOUR_SHARED_FOLDER_NAME 1
```

Then reboot your VM.

See https://www.virtualbox.org/ticket/10085#comment:12 for more information.